# Classify singularities of $\frac{e^z \sin(3z)}{(z-\sqrt2)(z+\sqrt2)z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

They are $0, \pm \sqrt2$. With the zero, $f(0)$ makes the numerator vanish and I have no idea how you would expand the whole function at $0$ because of the denominator. So what do you do to classify $0$?

I never know what to do in these situations!

Also correct me if I am wrong but for the other two, they are simple poles since they don't make the numerator vanish and they have degree one. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may observe that, as $z \to 0$,
$$
\frac{\sin(3z)}{z^2}=\frac{3z-9z^3/2+O(z^4)}{z^2}=\frac3z+O(z)
$$ thus $z=0$ is a simple pole for the initial function, as for the other two.

Comment: OK so this is what I am ruling myself to do in the future. If $f(z_0)$ makes the numerator vanish then only consider the numerator divided by the singularity and then expand and find type and residue so if for eg. which I just made up we have $$f(z)=\frac {\sin(z)}{e^z z^2 (z+2)}$$ has singularities $0$ and  $-2$. For $0$, it makes numerator vanish so consider $\sin(z)/z^2=1/z-z/6+...$ so it is a simple pole with residue $1$. And for $-2$, simple pole again since it doesn't make the numerator vanish and degree is $1$. Residue can be found by limit formula. Is everything I said correct?

Comment: @snowman The residue for your function in the comment above is the limit of $(z-0)f(z)$ as $z \to 0$, that is the limit of $\frac {\sin(z)}{e^z z (z+2)}$ as $z \to 0$, thus the residue at $0$ is $\dfrac12$. At $z=-2$, you consider the limit of $(z-(-2))f(z)=(z+2)f(z)$ as $z \to -2$, giving $-\frac {\sin(2)}{4}e^2$. Hoping to be clear.

Comment: @OliverOloa How is the residue $1/2$ at $z_0=0$? Because the coefficient of $\sin(z)/z^2$ of $1/(z-0)$ is $1$ so shouldn't the limit formula give $1$ too? Or can you not do the coefficient thing when dealing with these situations, since we never expanded everything.

Comment: @snowman Don't forget the other factors, here as $z \to 0$, we have $(z-0)f(z) \to   \frac {\sin(0)}{0}\frac {1}{e^0 (0+2)}=1 \times \dfrac12.$ Right?

Comment: @OliverOloa I know that the limit of (z-0)f(z) gives you half but I am saying that I find it strange that you cant look at the coefficient of 1/(z-0) which is the definition of residue.